# ghci self-referencing assignment

Tags: haskell, ghci

I was learning some new Haskell today, when I tried something in ghci.
It basically boiled down to this:

```
Prelude> let x = 6
Prelude> x
6
Prelude> let y = show x
Prelude> y
"6"
Prelude> let x = show x
Prelude> x
"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" --(repeats)
```

So can ghci not self-reference in assignment? I feel like it's akin to `i = i++;` in C, or trying to reference previous assignments of a `let` (not `let*`) in Scheme. Is there anyway to do this, or should I just use the easier `let y = show x`?

Comment: This problem was somehow mentioned on http://techblog.rosedu.org/haskell-part1.html

Comment: Note that the pattern exhibited actually does not repeat—the number of escaping backslashes increases exponentially and unboundedly.

Comment: We can even use Haskell to compute this! Try the following `let counts (c:cs) n = if c == '"' then n : counts cs 0 else counts cs (succ n)` then `x = show x` then `counts x 0` will give you `[0,1,3,7,15,31,63,127,255,511,1023,2047,4095,8191,16383,32767,65535,131071,262143,^CInterrupted.` which is `2^n - 1`. I say all this to drive home that just because something is an infinite loop in Haskell doesn't mean that we can't do useful things to it.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Coincidentally (or perhaps not), that's also the list `[2^x - 1|x <- [0..]`!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitions in Haskell are *recursive* by default. So the definition you made for `x` refers to the very same `x`, which is the reason for the very long string you are seeing, because `x` is defined to a `String` that is the result of calling `show` on itself, so you keep seeing the opening quotes for showing a string, and then those opening quotes escaped, and so on.

These kinds of definitions can be surprisingly useful. For example if you write:

```
let fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

you can define the Fibonacci sequence in terms of itself as an infinite list.

Then you can do something like `take 10 fibs` to just see the first 10 elements.

Answer (score 6):

It's self referencing indeed! It's trying to solve the equation

```
x = show x
```

Since `show` returns a string Haskell knows that `x` begins like `"\""` and that's enough to guess the *second* character, which is enough for the third which is enough for the fourth...

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do a not-selfreferencing assignment in ghci, although it's a bit cumbersome:

```
let x = 5
x <- return $ show x
```

`let`s are recursive, while monadic bindings are not.

Comment: That is still _not_ a self-referencing assignment. The two `x`es live in different namespaces, they're not the same object (and with `-Wall` your proposal causes ``Warning:
    This binding for `x' shadows the existing binding``).

Comment: Er... The question was "can ghci NOT self-reference in assignment". So, you're saying that I've got it right?

Answer (score 1):

Again: yes, Haskell very much can self-reference in assignment, otherwise this would just give an error instead of printing something undecipherable, wouldn't it?

What you can not do in Haskell, **ever**, is modify / *re-assign* the value of a variable. It's just totally out of question: if you've once defined `x` as some value, `x` will keep this value forever. An assumption baked into the very language, and used to great avail by the compiler for lots of optimisations etc..

Now you wonder why you can write `let x = ...` again at all, didn't I just say this is not possible? The thing is, what you're doing there is define a new variable that *also happens to have the name `x`*, but that doesn't change anything about the old variable with the same name. You might expect this

```
Prelude> let x = 6
Prelude> let p = print x
Prelude> let x = 7
Prelude> p
```

to yield `7`, but actually it prints `6` because `p` is still referring to the old variable `x`, not to the new one that was defined only later.

Still confused? Perhaps less strange is something like

```
n :: Int
n = 7

f :: IO ()
f = print $ replicate n "ha"

... -- much later, you've forgotten there was a global `n` up there...

g :: String -> String
g = take n
 where n = 37
```

It's quite reasonable that `f` will take 37 characters, not 7, while any call to `f` continues to repeat the string only 7 times. After all, it's "`g`, *where* `n` has that value", but nothing else outside. Now, `let` is just `where` written the other way around. In particular, a `do` notation or your GHCi prompt is actually syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
  let x = 6
  in ( print x >> ( let y = show x
                    in ( print y >> ( let x = show x
                                      in ( print x )
                                    )
                       )
     )
```

Each paren encloses a scope. Variables defined in outer scopes can be used, but local ones are preferred if found. So `let x = show x in ( print x )` can be considered completely on its own, the original `x = 6` is shadowed out of scope here. Therefore, the only way the definition can work is refer recursively to itself.